# Automapper: how to reverse a null substitute?

Tags: c#, automapper

I am relatively new to Automapper and just want to make sure I am not missing a shorter way to do this.  I have a field in the database that when it is null, the value in the corresponding model is set to the string literal "None".  I would like to do that logic in reverse when saving back to the database using the same mapperconfiguration if possible.  Here is the current code (field in question is the last ".ForMember"):

```
var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Location, LocationModel>()
    .ForMember(f => f.Name, db => db.MapFrom(f => f.LocationName))
    .ForMember(f => f.Description, db => db.MapFrom(f => f.LocationDescription))
    .ForMember(f => f.ERPCode, db => db.MapFrom(f => f.WarehouseCode))
    .ForMember(f => f.ERPCodeQBID, db => db.MapFrom(f => f.WarehouseCodeQBID))
    .ForMember(f => f.DefaultDispatchType, opt => opt.NullSubstitute("None")).ReverseMap());
```

The only way I have figured out to have "None" mapped back to null is to create a second map and not bother to reverse the one above.  If there is a way to achieve this, please let me know.

Comment: I don't have a way to repro here but can't you chain the `.ForMember()` right after `.ReverseMap()`, which then becomes a configuration for the LocationModel to Location?

Comment: That worked.  Do you want to post that as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain the `.ForMember()` right after `.ReverseMap()` using a fluent syntax, which then becomes a mapping configuration of the `LocationModel` to `Location`